# Zech Logarithms

Tags: finite-fields, coding-theory

> Let $a$ be a primitive element of $\mathbb{F}_{16}$ that satisfies the equation $a^4=1+a$.
>
> The logarithm of $1+a+a^2$ in $\mathbb{F}_{16}$ with base $a$ is the integer $i$ such that $0≤i<15$ and $1+a+a^2=a^i$.
>
> Give the logarithm of $1+a+a^2$ with base $a$.

From the first line we know that the Zech logarithm of $1$ is $4$, i.e. $Zech(1)=4$.

Also $a+a^2=a^{1+Zech(2-1)}=a^{5}$.

Now I am unsure of how to proceed. Any tips?

Comment: Many ways to continue. One way is to observe that as $a^5$ is a cubic root of unity, it belongs to the subfield of four elements consisting of fifth powers. The element $1+a+a^2=1+a^5$ must then also belong to this subfield, so it has to be $a^{10}$. In other words we must have $Zech(5)=10$.

Comment: The "easiest" way is to [take a peek](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/591253/11619).

Answer (score 2):

$a^4 = a +1$ so $1+a + a^2 = a^4+a^2$ but since we are in characteristic 2 we have that $a^4+a^2=(a^2+a)^2=(a*(a+1))^2=(a*a^4)^2=a^{10}$